# How to recognize redirect and submit in struts action

Tags: redirect, struts2, struts, submit, struts-action

My website use struts and tiles.
I use this link to link to register form:

```
<a href='<s:url action="register" namespace="/vtv"  />' >Register</a>
```

here is the register.jsp:

```
<s:form namespace="/vtv" action="register">
        <s:textfield label="Username" name="username" />
        <s:textfield label="Password" name="password" />
</s:form>
```

In action, i insert the user :

```
public String execute() {
    String retVal = ERROR;
    try {
            MemberDAO.InsertUser(mo);
            retVal = SUCCESS;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        retVal = ERROR;
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

in tiles file, i define:

```
<definition name="vtv.register" extends="basic">
    <put-attribute name="content" value="/modules/register/register.jsp" />
</definition>
```

and in struts file:

```
    <package name="Register" namespace="/vtv" extends="struts-default">
    <result-types>
        <result-type name="tiles"
                     class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult" />
    </result-types>
    <action name="register" class="vtv.action.RegisterAction">
        <result name="success" type="tiles">vtv.register</result>
        <result name="error" type="tiles">vtv.error</result>
    </action>
</package>
```

My problem is how can i redirect to register page using link

```
<a href='<s:url action="register" namespace="/vtv"  />' >Register</a>
```

without doing the execute in action ? How can i know if this is redirect or submit ?

Answer (score 0):

In your `<s:url>` tag you can specify a specific method you want to invoke in your RegisterAction:

```
<s:url action="register" method="yourRedirectMethodName" namespace="/vtv"  />
```

And then in your action define:

```
public String yourRedirectMethodName() {
    // Redirect logic
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

That way form submits will invoke execute() whereas the above link will invoke yourRedirectMethodName().

Comment: is there IsPostBack variable like Asp.net in struts ?

Comment: Not that I know of but something else that occurred to me is that you could check if your Action's form properties were set.  If yes, it's a form submit.  If no, it's a redirect from a link.